# Unable to get 'save' button to work

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do a course that is offered on PluralSight on Android development using java, and in the course you are making a notepad like app, and I am trying to get the save button to work, I'm using the same code that they are using in the tutorial, but it is not working for me for some reason, I am getting a null pointer exception, thanks!

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.notetaker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        final Button saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveButton.setText("clicked!");

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the logcat:

06-21 17:56:26.713: D/AndroidRuntime(1502): Shutting down VM
06-21 17:56:26.713: W/dalvikvm(1502): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3b0dba8)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502): Process: com.example.notetaker, PID: 1502
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.notetaker/com.example.notetaker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at com.example.notetaker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     ... 11 more

Comment: Possibly you have another saveButton id in another Activity xml file and the one in this Activity's xml is spelt wrong. Check your xml file!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your NullPointerException, it should tell you in which line you have the null pointer. Without that information it is very hard to help you. There are some places in this code where a NullPointer could happen, for example if a View is not found.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the LogCat, that is the line where the error is:

17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 06-21 17:56:26.743: E/AndroidRuntime(1502): at com.example.notetaker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29) 06-21 

Line 29 seems to be the line where you try to access the button. There might be another R.id.savebutton in another file so that it can not be found in the current view. In that case null will be returned and when you try to set the OnClickListener the null pointer will occur.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix the problem, it is still giving me the exact same error